# Cassandra cluster giving connection refused error when writing from hadoop using CQLOutputformat

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, cql3, cassandra-cli

I have a single node cassandra cluster which is *NOT* colocated with my hadoop cluster.  I'm using this hadoop cluster to bulk load data into a Cassandra cluster using CqlOutputFormat with following job configuration.

```
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    Configuration jobConf = job.getConfiguration();
    ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(jobConf, "10.27.124.73");
    ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(jobConf, "10.27.124.73");
    //ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(jobConf, "9160"); I tried setting the ports. Doesn't help. 
    //ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(jobConf, "9160");
    ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(jobConf,"Murmur3Partitioner");
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(jobConf, "Murmur3Partitioner");
    ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(jobConf, "pinspace", "pinseries");

    ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(jobConf, "pinspace", "pinseries");
    System.out.println(ConfigHelper.getOutputColumnFamily(jobConf));

    String query = "update pinspace.pinseries set timeseries = ?";

    CqlConfigHelper.setOutputCql(jobConf, query);
    CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(jobConf, "3");

    job.setInputFormatClass(BoomInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(GrepMapper.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setReducerClass(GrepReducer.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1024);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(CqlOutputFormat.class);
```

I get Connection refused error with the following stacktrace:

```
    Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:280)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(TFramedTransportFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyOutputFormat.createAuthenticatedClient(AbstractColumnFamilyOutputFormat.java:123)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:271)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
```

I'm using cassandra-driver-core 2.1.5 and cassandra-all 2.1.3.

The server is pingable using the given IP from the datanodes and telnet 10.27.124.73 9160 and telnet 10.27.124.73 9042 works.

EDIT:

I tried setting 9042 port in the code using, 
ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(jobConf, "9042");

Then the error changed to:

```
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2097152000)!
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.<init>(CqlRecordWriter.java:130)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.<init>(CqlRecordWriter.java:88)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlOutputFormat.java:74)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(CqlOutputFormat.java:55)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2097152000)!
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:608)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:595)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter.<init>(CqlRecordWriter.java:108)
        ... 11 more
```